# Collector not finding field

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8

I am trying to use a lambda to average a field over another grouped field. It fails and says it can't find field price. It does find the tradeMinutes field without problem. This would lead me to believe that it does now the correct class.

Compilation error in eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    price cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at com.simplegrowth.assets.AssetAdder.<init>(AssetAdder.java:60)
    at com.simplegrowth.Reader.<clinit>(Reader.java:23)
```

groupList function

```
        List<Asset> assetsList = null;

        assetsList = assets.get("BILL");
        assetsList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( a -> a.tradeMinutesSinceMidnight, Collectors.averagingDouble( a -> a.price) ) )
        .forEach((  tradeMinutesSinceMidnight, sumPrice) -> System.out.println(tradeMinutesSinceMidnight + " " + sumPrice));
```

The asset class

```
public class Asset implements Serializable, Comparable<Asset> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; // still set automatically

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    long sequenceNo;
    String Exchange;
    String Board;
    long time;
    String paper;
    long tradeTime;
    long quantity;
    double price;
    String source;
    String buyer;
    String seller;
    float changeSinceLast;
    String initator;
    long tradeTimeSinceMidnight;
    long tradeMinutesSinceMidnight;
    long daysSinceEpoch;


    public long getSequenceNo() {
        return sequenceNo;
    }
    public void setSequenceNo(long sequenceNo) {
        this.sequenceNo = sequenceNo;
    }
    public String getExchange() {
        return Exchange;
    }
    public void setExchange(String exchange) {
        Exchange = exchange;
    }
    public String getBoard() {
        return Board;
    }
    public void setBoard(String board) {
        Board = board;
    }
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public String getPaper() {
        return paper;
    }
    public void setPaper(String paper) {
        this.paper = paper;
    }
    public long getTradeTime() {
        return tradeTime;
    }
    public void setTradeTime(long tradeTime) {
        this.tradeTime = tradeTime;
    }
    public long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }
    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public String getBuyer() {
        return buyer;
    }
    public void setBuyer(String buyer) {
        this.buyer = buyer;
    }
    public String getSeller() {
        return seller;
    }
    public void setSeller(String seller) {
        this.seller = seller;
    }
    public float getChangeSinceLast() {
        return changeSinceLast;
    }
    public void setChangeSinceLast(float changeSinceLast) {
        this.changeSinceLast = changeSinceLast;
    }
    public String getInitator() {
        return initator;
    }
    public void setInitator(String initator) {
        this.initator = initator;
    }

    public long getDaysSinceEpoch() {
        return daysSinceEpoch;
    }
    public void setDaysSinceEpoch(long daysSinceEpoch) {
        this.daysSinceEpoch = daysSinceEpoch;
    }
    public long getTradeTimeSinceMidnight() {
        return tradeTimeSinceMidnight;
    }
    public void setTradeTimeSinceMidnight(long tradeTimeSinceMidnight) {
        this.tradeTimeSinceMidnight = tradeTimeSinceMidnight;
    }

    public long getTradeMinutesSinceMidnight() {
        return tradeMinutesSinceMidnight;
    }
    public void setTradeMinutesSinceMidnight(long tradeMinutesSinceMidnight) {
        this.tradeMinutesSinceMidnight = tradeMinutesSinceMidnight;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (sequenceNo == ((Asset)obj).sequenceNo)
            return true;
        return false;

        //return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Asset otherAsset) {
        if (this.getSequenceNo() < otherAsset.getSequenceNo()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: It compiles fine for me with javac. Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: As a side note, your `compareTo` method is broken. It should return `0` if the objects are equal. And your `equals` method is unnecessary complicated. Just say `return sequenceNo == ((Asset)obj).sequenceNo;`

Comment: Yes I am using eclipse.

Comment: So you can try to help that poor Eclipse compiler by using `Collectors.<Asset>averagingDouble( a -> a.price)`, or wait for an update…

Comment: That did it, excellent. Had no idea that eclipse could fail to use the standard compiler

Comment: Thanks Holger for noting that.